# Charindex update statement issue

Tags: sql, t-sql, indexing, sql-update, insert-update

Thank you in advance! I am working in SQL Server 2008 R2.

What I am trying to do is I have a text type column that has a first and last name and then shows a ^, what I want to do is capture that text leading up to the ^ (so essnetially the first and last name) and append it to the very bottom of another column (not replace) within the same table.

I have tried using charindex but I just receieve the index number and I can't seem to get it to capture the text before the ^ appears, I just get the position of the ^ and also I am having a hard time appending this
text chunk to another text type column within the same table. For this I have been trying the updatetext function but it doesn't seem to work. I have scrapped what I have tried thus far because I have gotten anywhere without errors.

So in summary:

I need to capture text at the beginning of a text data type column until it reaches a ^ symbol

Save that text to some sort of variable.

Place (append), along with slight additions, into another text data type column.

It seems like it should be simple but I am having a difficult time, Please make recommendations if possible.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, let's find the starting position of the `^` in `col1`:

```
CHARINDEX('^', col1)
```

We will then use `LEFT` to return the left part of the column by specifying the number of characters to return. However, since the `^` is at the starting position, we need to subtract 1.

```
LEFT(col1, CHARINDEX('^', col1) - 1)
```

We then use `+` (`CONCAT` in 2012+) to concatenate another column (`col2`) to this:

```
col2 + LEFT(col1, CHARINDEX('^', col1) - 1)
```

If you need to make other additions, you can separate the string values using a plus:

```
'Hello' + ' ' + 'World'
```

The final statement may look something like:

```
SELECT col2 + LEFT(col1, CHARINDEX('^', col1) - 1) AS col
```

**Update**

If there are some values that do not have a `^`, you will need a `CASE` statement to prevent receiving the *"Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function"* error:

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN CHARINDEX('^', col1) > 0
      THEN LEFT(col1, CHARINDEX('^', col1) - 1)
    ELSE col1
  END AS col
```

Comment: SQL Server before 2012 does not know CONCAT. Just use + instead: col2 + LEFT(col1, CHARINDEX('^', col1) - 1)

Comment: I get "Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function."  When Using

Answer (score 0):

CharIndex gives you the numeric position of the character you were looking for.  You need to use that in another function, like LEFT or RIGHT, to get the desired substring. This is how you would get the first part of a field before an ^ character:

```
SELECT LEFT(SomeField, CharIndex('^', SomeField) - 1)
```

(You subtract one to exclude the ^ from your substring.)